# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined - expressjs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to learn one to many relationship in MongoDB using mongoose and expressjs. I am trying to use reference method in which only id is stored as a reference.

User has already been created. Here is my code -

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//saving application name in mongodb and connecting to it
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blog_demo_3");

//POST - title, content
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String
});


var Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

//USER - name email
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    name: String,
   //linking to many posts specific to user one to many relation    
posts: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Post"
    }
]
});

var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

Post.create({
    title: "How to cook burger pt 2",
    content: "blah blah blah"
}, function(err, post){
    User.find({name: "Bob Fischer"}, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else {
            //foundUser.posts.pus(post) - doesn't works
            foundUser.posts.push(post._id);
            foundUser.save(function(err, data){
                if(err)
                    console.log(err)
                else
                    console.log(data);
            });
        }
    });
});

 // User.create({
 //     email: "bob@foodtech.com",
 //     name: "Bob Fischer"
 // }, function(err, createdBlog){
 //     if(err)
 //         console.log(err);
 //     else
 //         console.log(createdBlog);
 // });
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(foundUser)` just above the `push` i.e, `foundUser.posts.push(post._id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for not noticing such small syntax error.

```
User.find({name: "Bob Fischer"}, function(err, foundUser){
```

should be

```
User.findOne({name: "Bob Fischer"}, function(err, foundUser){
```